# deleting entry widgets in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying to delete the the entry widget with a button but keep getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

I shortened my code to:

```
from tkinter import *
e = object()

def getname():
    global name
    e = Entry(root, textvariable=name)
    e.pack()
    e.focus_set()
    b = Button(root, text = "Get", width = 10, command = callback)
    b.pack()
    b2 = Button(root, text = "Delete", width = 10, command = delete_entry)
    b2.pack()

def callback():
    username = name.get()
    print(username)

def delete_entry():
    e.delete(0, "end")

root = Tk()
name = StringVar()
getname()
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Are you aware you have both a global and local variable named `e`, and that they are two different things?

Comment: no sorry i was unaware, thanks for the input i ended up solving the problem by adding "global e"

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code ( which delete the Entry box totally):

```
def delete_entry():
    e.destroy()
```

Or do you only want to delete the text within the Entry widget? Tell me and I will update my answer.

Comment: No, `pack_forget()` doesn't delete the entry widget. It hides it from view but the widget still exists.